# Q: Calculating a MPI cluster throughtput from hardware latencies

Tags: linear-bounded-automata

Since i don't have a CS background in my career,
Built up an *openmpi* compute platform which succesfully computes from a variable number of available nodes. call this whole, a ***mpi cluster*** having N^2 **4-Core-CPU** + **16-OpenCL-1.1-compute-cores** with a reasonable compute power each node.

I have no experience in parallel optimizations of algorithms thus i've processed diferent segments of a  in 'distances' from a norm (semi-random parameters with a regular metrics).
Current online setup is 2-node each 4*2600Mhz + 16*1440Mhz for solver and a network bandwidth of 1 Gigabit/s per node *switched* at 1Gb/s. 
1. How would one integrate a computation time from a series of latency values delivered from each node such as the sum of all hardware latencies involved.
 
2. Do i need a quadratic time solver feeded with latencies to get a 'deviation' or something like that? many thanks.

Comment: If by any chance you are the official author and have inadvertently created two accounts, I encourage you to [merge them](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts); that will ensure you retain access, are able to edit your question without needing approval from others, and will provide you with the ability to leave comments under your question or under answers.

Comment: aside i couldn't delete the original question made from a no-account post, but the interface is friendly but editing everything isn't simple to fit a single thread from several questions each post. so i've considered the particular question void, hoping to find more brief and direct 'queries' next time. it didn't take a lot of time to share as it takes to appreciate the environmental efforts for the poster/editors. i'm fine with that. i hope you accept, thank you.